# Fan control for i5 in Lenovo T520 not working

Tags: xubuntu, fan, fancontrol

I have a [Lenovo T520](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t520/), which is annoyingly loud all the time. My CPU however doesn't do anything and the BIOS is set to "balanced mode".

I tried to check, and the fan control is set to automatic, and even correctly tells the fan to run at low speeds or turn off:

```
root@xubuntu:~# cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 
status:     enabled
speed:      1974
level:      auto

root@xubuntu:~# cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 
status:     enabled
speed:      0
level:      auto
```

However, my fan is ignoring that completely, running happily all the time on full speed despite having the `ondemand` governor set:

```
tux@xubuntu:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
ondemand
```

Comment: Why do you have different contents of the same file? Is the second what you get when the fan is idle? Does that mean the fan _does_ stop sometimes? Please post the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: The fan should be idle, but is still running. even if i get 0 rpm, i can hear it running...     
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
ondemand

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1. ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059548&page=4)) Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `acpi_osi='Linux'` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='Linux'"
   ```

   Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.
2. For tips on controlling a Lenovo's fan, have a look at [this page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed). The thinkwiki webpage in general is always a great source of info for Linux on Lenovo machines.
3. There is a very nice utility called "[Simple ThinkPad Fan Control](https://github.com/Stanko/ThinkPad-Fan-Control)" which allows you to fine tune the trigger temperatures that change the fan's speed.
4. If you are on a Dell machine (I know you are not, but someone else may read this), use the i8k module:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install i8kutils 
   sudo modprobe i8k
   sudo i8kfan 0 1
   ```
5. If you are dual booting with windows, check the fan settings there. I had a similar problem and the power settings in windows were making changes in the BIOS which then would affect my linux system as well.